# problem on sending push notification to android devices through parse on my own server

Tags: android, firebase, parse-platform, push-notification

i'm using parse push notification with [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/yongjhih/parse-server).

after configuration server and dashboard sending object with curl is fine. 
but i'm confuse how to using this server to send push notification to android devices! on my server i cant have internet connection all time and my question is fcm is optional for sending push? or is the only way to receive push from android devices from parse server?

after running my app with below codes, the installation record is saved and i can see that from parse dashboard. but when sending push android device doesn't receive push. 
is parse need to connect parse server to Firebase? (if yes, how can configure to integrate fcm with parse ) (if no, how can configure parse server or android app for receiving pushes?)

here is my implementation:

(the google-services.json is added to app directory)

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.project"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1" 
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:1.20.0"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.20.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
}
```

Application class:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        builder.networkInterceptors().add(httpLoggingInterceptor);

Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("APP_ID")
                .enableLocalDataStore()
                .server("http://ServerIp:1337/parse/")
                .clientBuilder(builder)
                .build()
        );
        Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("channel1", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Successfully subscribed to Parse!");
            }
        });

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Manifest services and receivers :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.test.project">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="ir.meedc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ir.meedc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <receiver
            android:name=".service.parsePush"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />


                <category android:name="info.androidhive.parsenotifications" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>-->

        <service
            android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityMain"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</manifest>
```

installation record is saved.

[image: installation record on dashboard]

some of pushes that send from dashboard or api with curl.

[image: sent pushes]

**(Solved)**
finally i figure out the configuration can be pass to parse-server initialize command. just need to create a file and pass it to parse-server command.

Comment: Yes. Parse Server requires FCM in order to send push notifications to Android devices. Please refer to this guide here on how to setup.: https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#setting-up-push

Comment: @DaviMacêdo thanks, so i need internet connection all the time on my own server.